# Creating a custom search for month year in a single column in datatables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table with search bars in each column in it's footer. The search for each column is working as expected. But the problem comes when it is on the column of the date.

My current format of the date is `"mm/dd/yyyy"`

When I try to input `"mm/yyyy"`for example `"03/2023"` I would get values with day year `"dd/yyyy"` like `["01/03/2023","02/03/2023", "04/03/2023"]`. Which is not intended since I want to get all the dates within the given month and year.

So I tried using `DataTable.ext.search.push` function from datatables. first I wanted to preserve the global search so I included:

```
 if (inputData === '') {
    return true;
}
```

Then I wanted to filter if given input with the format of `"mm/yyyy"` is valid and if either year or month is equal to the input.

```
return (
     isValidDate(inputData, 'MM/yyyy') &&
     inputDate.year === rowDate.year ||
     inputDate.month === rowDate.month
);
```

This logic gives me the same problem where `"dd/yyyy"` data is shown not `"mm/yyyy"`
How can I fix my logic or code in order for me to filter the correct data? I tried asking chatGPT but it suggests the same logic and same outcome. Also if there is a better way to filter or refactor my code please feel free to suggest.

For more context here is a much larger snippet of my current code.

```
            $('.table-resize tfoot th').each(function(i) {
                if (headerLen - 1 != i) {
                    var title = $('.table-resize thead th').eq(i).text();
                    $(this).html(
                        '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control ' + (title ==
                            'Date Sourced' ? 'ds_search' : '') + '" type="text" placeholder="' +
                        title +
                        '" data-index="' + i + '" /></div>');
                }

            });
            table = $('.table-resize').DataTable({
                scrollY: "500px",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollResize: true,
                pageResize: true,
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 5,
                },
                drawCallback: function(settings) {
                    $('.table-loading-cont').removeClass('d-flex').css('display', 'none')
                    $('.table-resize').removeClass('d-none')
                    resizeTable()
                }
            });

            $(table.table().container()).on('keyup change', 'tfoot input', function() {
                table
                    .column($(this).data('index'))
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw()
            });

            DataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var searchData = data[1];
                var inputData = $($('tfoot .ds_search')[1]).val();

                if (inputData === '') {
                    return true;
                }

                var inputDate = getDate(inputData, 'MM/yyyy');
                var rowDate = getDate(searchData);

                return (
                    isValidDate(inputData, 'MM/yyyy') &&
                    inputDate.year === rowDate.year ||
                    inputDate.month === rowDate.month
                );
            });
```

**EDIT:**

I found a work around. I would get the month from the column search and I would get the year in the global search.

```
DataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var searchData = data[1];
                var inputData = $($('tfoot .ds_search')[1]).val();

                if (inputData == '' ||
                    isValidDate(inputData) ||
                    (inputData.length == 2 && parseInt(inputData) == getDate(searchData).month)
                ) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            });
```

This solution gives me the intended output. However, it is not intuitive for the user since the user would utilize 2 search bars at once. So the question now is: Is there a better way to do this with only one input from the column search bar?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on code from: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

When searching for "03/2023" one gets "01/03/2023", "02/03/2023", and "04/03/2023".

```js
new DataTable('#example', {
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api()
      .columns()
      .every(function() {
        let column = this;
        let title = column.footer().textContent;

        // Create input element
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.placeholder = title;
        column.footer().replaceChildren(input);

        // Event listener for user input
        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
          if (column.search() !== this.value) {
            column.search(input.value).draw();
          }
        });
      });
  }
});
```

```css
tfoot input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>04/03/2023</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>01/03/2023</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>02/03/2023</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>03/29/2023</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>03/28/2023</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>12/02/2023</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

### Solution 1

Following https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html, this solution uses a custom regular expression search internally by converting a date-like text of the form "MM/YYY" to a regular expression.

When the user types "03/2023" in this new search box, the input text gets converted to the regular expression `03\d{2}2023` and the result of this search are the records with start date "03/28/2023" and "03/29/2023".

```js
let table = new DataTable('#example', {
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api()
      .columns()
      .every(function() {
        let column = this;
        let title = column.footer().textContent;
        // Create input element
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.placeholder = title;
        column.footer().replaceChildren(input);
        // Event listener for user input
        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
          if (column.search() !== this.value) {
            column.search(input.value).draw();
          }
        });
      });
  }
});


function isValidDate(value) {
  // matches 1/2023, 01/2023, 1/3/2023, 01/03/2023, etc.
  return /^\d{1,2}(\/\d{1,2})?\/\d{4}$/.test(value)
}

function filterColumn(table, i) {
  let filter = document.querySelector('#col' + i + '_filter');
  let regex = document.querySelector('#col' + i + '_regex');
  if (isValidDate(filter.value) && filter.value.length < 8) {
    // form regular expression from MM/YYYY
    let myRegex = filter.value.split('/').join('/\\d{2}/');
    console.log("Search for matching:", myRegex);
    table.column(i).search(myRegex, regex = true).draw();
  } else {
    table.column(i).search(filter.value).draw();
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('input.column_filter').forEach((el) => {
  let tr = el.closest('tr');
  let columnIndex = tr.getAttribute('data-column');
  el.addEventListener(el.type === 'text' ? 'keyup' : 'change', () =>
    filterColumn(table, columnIndex)
  );
});
```

```css
tfoot input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto 2em auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="filter_col5" data-column="4">
      <td><b>Search by month MM/YYYY</b></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col4_filter"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>04/03/2023</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>01/03/2023</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>02/03/2023</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>03/29/2023</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>03/28/2023</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>12/02/2023</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

### Solution with a custom search

`#customsearch`

```js
let table = new DataTable('#example');


function isValidDate(value) {
  // matches 1/2023, 01/2023, 1/3/2023, 01/03/2023, etc.
  return /^\d{1,2}(\/\d{1,2})?\/\d{4}$/.test(value)
}

const customsearch = document.querySelector('#customsearch');

DataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  if (isValidDate(customsearch.value) && customsearch.value.length < 8) {
    // convert search string to MM/YYYY
    customsearch.value = customsearch.value.padStart(7, "0");
    let myDate = data[4].split('/');
    myDate = myDate[0] + '/' + myDate[2];
    //console.log(customsearch.value, myDate,"it's a match?", customsearch.value==myDate);
    return customsearch.value == myDate;
  }
  return true;
});

customsearch.addEventListener('input', function() {
  table.draw();
});
```

```css
tfoot input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto 2em auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="filter_col5" data-column="4">
      <td><b>Search by month MM/YYYY</b></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="customsearch"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>04/03/2023</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>01/03/2023</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>02/03/2023</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>03/29/2023</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>03/28/2023</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>12/02/2023</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However I am thinking why did you not use the custom search function? `DataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {`

Comment: @MendrixManlangit sorry about the confusion as our friend always says :D, I edited the answer adding a custom search field

Comment: no problem :D another followup question would be if I were to scale this up to multiple columns and with dates with their respective search bars, what are the things I might consider?

Comment: a dropdown next to the `#customsearch` input field where the user can select which column to search. In the example it's the 5th column (`data[4]`).

Comment: Thank you for your wise words. I will look into your solution and I will give updates. :)